# how to open umbraco website completely in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, umbraco

I Copied everything from IIS into my visual studio website application and it gives me error. which goes into install folder asking for runway-content missing error
.         App_Browsers

·         app_code

·         bin

·         config

·         css

·         data

·         masterpages

·         media

·         scripts

·         Umbraco

·         umbraco_client

·         usercontrols

·         xslt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not much to go on as a question, but I'll try to help.

If the site was deployed to IIS, it may well be missing some source elements (especially if it was deployed with the 'only enough elements to run' (sic) option).  So installing Umbraco locally seems like a good first step.

If you're missing runway content aspects then the original site was probably built with the runway starter kit, so to fix it I would consider installing Umbraco on your development machine and then copying the stuff you've recovered from your server (http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/getting-started/what-are-runway-and-modules.aspx).

HTH

Comment: Thanks,amelvin. one more question can i work on umbraco direct source file and develop a site.

Comment: You can work directly on .master, .ascx, .css, .cshtml, .js files - but you can't avoid using Umbraco admin if you want the site to work.